# Actualizar registros en una tabla footable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Como puedo cargar los datos que recibo desde una petición post con AJAX en un datatable, tengo el siguiente script:

```js
$("#status").change(function () {
                    
                    
                    var respuestaAJAX = new String();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "DatosUsuarios.do",
                        data: {
                            Filtro: $("#status option:selected").text(),
                            Action: "Filtrar"
                        },
                        success: function (response)
                        {
                            
                            $("#tUsuarios").footable({
                                "sorting": {
                                    "enabled": true
                                },
                                "toggleSelector": ".footable-toggle",
                                "columns": [
                                    {"name": "Nombre", "title": "Nombre"},
                                    {"name": "id", "title": "id", "visible": false},
                                    {"name": "Email", "title": "Email"},
                                    {"name": "cuenta", "title": "cuenta", "visible": false},
                                    {"name": "Perfil", "title": "Perfil"},
                                    {"name": "Estado", "title": "Estado"},
                                    {"name": "Action", "title": "Acción"}
                                ],
                                "rows":
                });
                            
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Que debo colocar ahi en "rows" para que mi tabla se cargue con esos datos, los datos los tengo en formato JSON en response.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué formato tiene `response`? ¿Recibes algún error?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro el response tiene formato JSON, no recibo ni un error, solo que no me carga los datos en la tabla

Comment: No se usa `response` en ningún lado. ¿Cómo le pasas los datos a footable?

Comment: Aque te refienes con que no se usa response en ningun lado? @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: En el `success` recibes los datos en la variable `response`, pero luego `response` no se usa en la función ni en la llamada a footable, por lo que no parece que se estén leyendo/escribiendo los datos en ningún sitio. Además, te preguntaba por el formato interno, la estructura del JSON que llega en el `response`.

Comment: A ok, Si... yo lo que estaba intentando hacer era asignarle a rows la variable response, pero no me lo permite, no me da error, pero tampoco carga los datos en la tabla. response contiene los registros de los usuarios que quiero cargar en la tabla, en formato JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72181/discussion-between-afar1793-and-alvaro-montoro).

Comment: He probado el código que compartes con la respuesta que recibes (disponible en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72181/discussion-between-afar1793-and-alvaro-montoro)) y me funciona sin problemas ([JSFiddle con demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ev8au4bk/)). Si no hay errores en la consola de JS, no sé que puede ser lo que esté fallando en concreto. Todo se ve bien.